# IAM Policy restricted to load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-policy

I spent the last 2 hours trying to create a policy that would give all the permissions to an user for a specific load balancer.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "elasticloadbalancing:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:123456789012:loadbalancer/core"
    }
]
}
```

I checked '123456789012' multiple times to be the correct. I took the 'Account Id' attribute from [here](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?#/account).

I checked 'core' multiple times and even tried to replace it with '*' but it didn't work.

I also double checked the region to make sure it's the correct one.

On the other hand, if I replace the whole ARN with '*', it works but I don't want this, I want it to be specific to a load balancer.

Thanks,
Gabriel

Comment: is "core" the name of the elb o just a fake name to explain the case? I am looking at my elbs and the name is a bit longer than yours: XXXXXXXX.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com

Comment: Also for above policy what will the user do with the specific load balancer? And what error is the above policy throwing?

Answer (score 2):

the name was correct, the problem was about how AWS works. You have to let the user describe the resource before giving him permissions. Here is a policy that works:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "elasticloadbalancing:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:123456789012:loadbalancer/core"
    }
]
}
```

Thanks